# How to write test class for selectionoptions?

Tags: unit-test

I have write this class in Salesforce but not able write test class. Please anybody can help me to write test class.

This is my controller class:

```
public class AccountRelatedContacts  {
        public id tobeEdited{get; set;}
        public String selectedcouId{get;set;}
        public String selectedAccId{get;set;}
        public string conid{get;set;}
        public boolean showPopup{ get; set; }
         public boolean isDownload {get;set;}

        public list<contact> lstcontact{get;set;}


         public List<SelectOption> getCountryNames() {

                 List<SelectOption> couOptions= new List<SelectOption>();
                          couOptions.add( new SelectOption('','--Select--'));
                          list<Country__c> cut = [select Id,name from Country__c];
                          for( Country__c  cou : cut ) {
                                  couOptions.add( new SelectOption(cou.Id,cou.name));
                          }
                         return couOptions;
                   }            

               public List<SelectOption> getAccountNames() {
               system.debug('country ID'+selectedcouid);
                  List<SelectOption> accOptions= new List<SelectOption>();
                  List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
                  if(selectedcouId != null){

                  list<account> act = [select Id,name,Country__c from account where Country__c=:selectedcouId order by name ASC ];

                  for( Account acc : act  ) {
                          accOptions.add( new SelectOption(acc.Id,acc.name)); 
                  }
                  }
               else
                    {
                        accOptions.add( new SelectOption('--None--','--None--'));
                    }
             return accOptions;
       }

      public pagereference Submit(){

      lstcontact= new List<contact>();
      lstcontact= [SELECT ID,name, Firstname,lastname,email,phone,account.name from contact WHERE accountId=:selectedaccid order by name ASC];
      return null;
    }
}
```

could you please tell me writing test code.

Answer (score 2):

In your second test `testgetCountryNames` you call:

```
controllers.getaccountNames();
```

method immediately before your set the country ID value in the next line with:

```
controllers.selectedcouId = c.id;
```

Change the order of these statements.

Consistent indenting would make it easier for you and others to understand your code.

Comment: +1 for the gentle admonition on indenting; Improving the world of software development, one OP at a time :-)

Comment: Hi I changed order of there two stateemnts again it will show error only code not covering,country id showing null

Comment: can any one help on this